# How to programatically check/uncheck all checkboxes?

Tags: python, streamlit

I have created a list of checkboxes in the loop (for every row in the dataframe):

```
options = []
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    option = st.sidebar.checkbox(label=f"{row['title']} ({row['option']})", key=idx)
    options.append([row['title'], option])
```

By default, all the checkboxes are unchecked which is as desired.

Upon checking/unchecking any checkbox, the interface is updated, which is also ok.
In order not to check/uncheck every checkbox in case the user wants so select/deselect all, I have created buttons and assigned the function calls:

```
def select_all_fields():
    options = []
    for idx, row in gdf_paper_dry_run.iterrows():
        option = st.sidebar.checkbox(label=f"{row['label']} ({row['option']})", key=idx, value=True)
        options.append([row['label'], option])
        
def clear_all_fields(options_list):
    options = []
    for idx, row in gdf_paper_dry_run.iterrows():
        option = st.sidebar.checkbox(label=f"{row['label']} ({row['option']})", key=idx, value=False)
        options.append([row['label'], option])
```

This, however, doesn't work. Does anyone know how to select/deselect all the checkboxes from the list programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of callback and [session_states](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/session-state).

```
import streamlit as st


def sel_callback():
    st.session_state.a = st.session_state.sel
    st.session_state.b = st.session_state.sel

st.write('### Control')
st.checkbox('select all', key='sel', on_change=sel_callback)

st.write('### main')
st.checkbox('a', key='a')
st.checkbox('b', key='b')
```

#### Output

[image]